# ffmpeg subprocess issue

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

this works fine when tried thru the python script editor in maya. how to make sure it runs successfully even when running thru a script

```
oneImage = "D:/imagesequence/dpx/brn_055.0000.jpg"
firstImage = "c:/users/nishith/appdata/local/temp/firstImage.jpg"
thumbnai = "c\:/users/nishith/appdata/local/temp/thumbnail.jpg"

paramf = "movie='%s' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3[water];[water] drawtext=fontsize=32:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='shotName':x=(w)/2:y=(h)-50,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Notes \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-90,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Frame Range \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-130,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Lens \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-170,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Undistortion \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-210,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Image Sequence \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-250,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Date \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-290,drawtext=fontsize=28:fontcolor=White:fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='Element Name \:':x=(w)/5:y=(h)-330,drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='FIREWORKS':x=130:y=200:fontsize=54:fontcolor=White[out]" % thumbnai

d = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-threads", "8", "-i", firstImage , "-vf", paramf , oneImage], shell=True)
```

Comment: Does it not run successfully now?  What happens?  Do you get an error?

Comment: CalledProcessError: raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd): .. returned non-zero exit status 1 #

Comment: ffmpeg, most of the time, will write a bunch of things to stderr and finish with a non-zero status. You will have to parse its output to see if it did what you want.

Comment: Did `ffmpeg` produce any output?

Comment: got it. though on command line it worked. subprocess command 'C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf' was missing in drawtext. For now it worked with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. though on command line it worked. subprocess command 'C\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf' was missing in drawtext. For now it worked with the changes.